# jQuery function shows in console but not in browser on first click, then shows twice in browser on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty befuddled by this bug. Throughout my javascript file, my jQuery functions (like the one at the bottom of the page) don't act on the first click, but act twice on the second click. I'm running Bootstrap as well.

Thanks.

```
var showLocation = function () {
    console.log("executing showLocation()\n");
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#show-game-button").click(function() {
                $(".location-div").show(300);
                    $("#show-game-button").css('display', 'none');
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is `showLocation` called multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding new click listener every time you execute your function. 
This should be working fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#show-game-button").click(function() {
            $(".location-div").show(300);
                $("#show-game-button").css('display', 'none');
        });
});
```

you don't need the `showLocation` function.